# jQuery Mobile Change page not loading page already in DOM

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am loading an JqueryMobile Page `Home` in my application and on `pageinit` I am navigating to web/mobile external page (say `B`) using `$.mobile.changePage('webWatch.html'`...

Now, when I am trying to changePage from `B` to `Home`, which is already in DOM and attributed as `data-dom-cache=true`, there is nothing happening. I am not getting any error or action on the page.

Any suggestions how to get this thing work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use absolute URLs so the URL you ask for matches the `data-url` attribute of the page.

For example, if a file is in the `/watch/` folder (within the root directory of your account), you can setup it's `data-url` attribute before jQuery Mobile does:

```
<div data-dom-cache="true" data-role="page" data-url="/watch/default.html">
    ...
</div>
```

This way you know it's setup correctly and you don't have to worry about the relativity of assets. Then when you link to the page use the absolute URL:

```
<a data-role="button" href="/watch/default.html">Go to /watch/default.html</a>
```

This way when you click the `Go to /watch/default.html` link, jQuery Mobile will search the current pseudo-pages for the one with the `data-url` attribute that matches the `href` attribute of the link.